# Tailwind tooltip rounded arrow

Tags: css, tailwind-css, border, rounded-corners

I am trying to make a tooltip using TailwindCss but I am facing a problem as I am not very good with border manipulation

Example of how I want it to look:
[image: Example of how I want it to look]

I am able to round the tip of the arrow by making a rounded triangle and adding it on top, but in this way I can't make the bottom parts that continue to be rounded.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You'd need to look at using an SVG or similar to get the roundedness of it

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/rabit1977/TailwindCssExercissing/blob/master/nextjs-app/my-app/app/globals.css
Go to this link and find the tooltip in file-"globalcss", at @layer components, and add it wherever you want, edit, add new stuff .... and use it
This is my version....
you can upgrade it ...